# Get an array through a closure. Swift

Tags: swift, closures, alamofire

I am studying networking (Alamofire).
And in his pet project on Viper architecture.
I am making a **get** request and getting a to-do list from a local server.
The data is returned to me successfully.
But I just can't figure out how to get them and transfer them to Interactor...

I want my `fetchToDos` method to return an array. But I keep making mistakes.

```swift
func fetchToDos() -> [ToDo]? { // <- My mistake is clearly here

    let request = Session.default.request("http://localhost:3003/")

    request.responseDecodable(of: ToDos.self) { (response) in

        switch response.result {
        case .success(let tasks):
            print("SUCCESS to FETCH JSON: \(tasks)")
        case .failure(let error):
            print("FAILED to FETCH JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using an asynchronous function, and so one way to get something out
of it when it is finished, is to use a completion handler, something like this:
(note you need to do the error checking etc...before you can use this for real)

```
class ToDoNetworking {

    func fetchToDos(completion: @escaping ([ToDo] -> Void)) { // <- try this
        let request = Session.default.request("http://localhost:3003/")
        request.responseDecodable(of: [ToDos].self) { (response) in

            switch response.result {
            case .success(let tasks):
                print("SUCCESS to FETCH JSON: \(tasks)")
                completion(tasks) // <-- assuming tasks is [ToDo]
            case .failure(let error):
                print("FAILED to FETCH JSON: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion([])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the type of data being returned by the network call?  If it's an array of ToDo objects and your ToDo object supports Codable, then it's likely you want:

`request.responseDecodable(of: [ToDo].self)`

you pass in the type of object that you want to decode, which it sounds like, is an array of ToDo objects, hence `[ToDo].self`.